# Android generic ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have multiple classes, which all extend some BasicDataModel:

```
public class NewsItem extends BasicDataModel
public class PhotosItem extends BasicDataModel
```

etc. So I need to make ArrayAdapters for all of them, and I wonder if it is possible to make some generic ArrayAdapter to fit all my objects. So far I tried to make

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BasicDataModel>
```

but as long as I pass ArrayList, for example, this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
public class MyAdapter<T extends BasicDataModel> extends ArrayAdapter<T>
```

and use

```
MyAdapter<NewsItem> news;
```

Comment: only change I made is    extends ArrayAdapter<BasicDataModel>

Answer (score 2):

I tried Nikita Beloglazov suggestion:

```
public class MyAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T extends BasicDataModel>
```

but found that it wouldn't compile.

Then I tried:

```
public class MyAdapter<T extends BasicDataModel> extends ArrayAdapter<T>
```

and that worked just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the PIArrayAdapter.
reduce your code size and headache of maintaining it again.
just plug and play with simple annotations

pull it @
https://github.com/peeyush18/CustomAdapter.git

or view it at
https://github.com/peeyush18/CustomAdapter